# How to change current work directory using expect script?

Tags: shell, expect

I want to write an expect script which can do some task and in the end change the directory and give control to the user. I tried using

`spawn cd path\to\dir
 interact`

but i am still in the same directory. 
Any leads on how to accomplish this using expect ?

Comment: Simply use `cd <dst-dir>`. It will change the directory.

Comment: As Dinesh said you can sinply change directory using `cd path_to_dir`, why did you thought about Expect?

Comment: Expect is an extension of the Tcl language, and `cd` is [one of the built-in Tcl commands](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you have *spawn*ed some command (like *ssh*, *bash*) and the *spawn*ed command is still running. Then at the end you can do like this:

```
send "cd /some/dir\r"
interact
```

Comment: It worked!! I am doing
`spawn zsh
send "cd /some/dir\r"
interact`
But why am i not able to do it using spawn cd ?

Comment: @maximus -- The `spawn` command only works with *external* command (which is located in a filesystem). There's no such an *external* `cd` command (like `/bin/cd`, `/usr/bin/cd`).

Answer (score 6):

To change the directory in an expect script, you don't need to use the keyword "spawn" it works without it.
You may be a little confused, because in the terminal, in which you are executing the script, you will stay in the same directory, but the script changed the directory in which it is doing things.

Comment: Good answer @GitZwergrapper - exactly what I was looking for. simply putting "cd <local-directory-path>" switches the directory. This may not be obvious unless you utilise a "spawn" then interact. Thanks