# changing directory using bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I am trying to SSH into a server and run a program. I was able to SSH using

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh username@serveraddress
expect "assword:"
send "mypassword/r"
#interact
cd /users/bill/work
```

But then I wanted to change to a specific directory and execute a program from that directory. So when it gets to cd part, I keep getting

```
couldn't change working directory to "/users/bill/work/": no such file or directory
while executing
"cd /users/bill/work/"
(file "./ssh.sh" line 8)
```

but I know that is a correct directory and I can cd to it from the interact command line. so, can I even use cd command if I am using expect?

Thank you,
BZ

Comment: Check if this may help: [how-to-change-current-work-directory-using-expect-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720111/)

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849669/writing-automated-scripts-to-configure-device/42856437#42856437

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that, once you log in via ssh, you want to access the remote computers console. However, `cd /users/bill/work` is being executed on your system, as you are not typing it into the console, but executing it directly from the bash file, where truly no such file or directory exists. You might want to send the command instead to the remote computers conosle.

Comment: How do I access the remote computer's console? isn't sshing good enough?

Comment: @B.Z., you do this: `send cd /usres/bill/work\r` -- that executes the command in the ssh process that you spawned. The "\r" represents you hitting the enter key. This is very basic expect: you might want to find a tutorial or read [the book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do) to get going.